# Can I combined a Sneak Attack with Volley and Assassinate as a Ranger 11/Rogue 9?

Tags: dnd-5e, rogue, ranger, sneak-attack

Am I able to combine the Sneak Attack (Rogue 9) and Volley (Ranger 11) class features to basically create a wall of arrows and death while hidden inside a bush, sneak attacking a mass of enemies, and get automatic criticals from Assassinate?

I've read pages 90–93, 95–97 of the D&D 5e PHB.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yes, you can combine Volley with Assassinate, but not fully with Sneak Attack.

> Once per turn, you can deal an extra 1d6 damage to one creature you
>   hit with an attack (PHB 96 on Sneak Attack)

Volley only lets you make multiple attacks with a single Action. It does not let you bypass the once per turn limitation of Sneak Attack. You can only add the bonus damage to one of your hits.

> You have advantage on attack rolls against **any** creature that hasn't
>   taken a turn in the combat yet. In addition, **any** hit you score against
>   a creature that is surprised is a criticai hit. (PHB 97 on Assassinate, emphasis mine)

This feature has only one limitation: that the target did not have a turn yet. If you have multiple attacks, each of them will benefit from this feature if your target has not acted yet.

Comment: Could you please clarify whether the extra damage of the one *Sneak Attack* per round stacks with the extra damage of critical hits (provoked by *Assassinate* or otherwise)? I believe that's still part of the question. I only remember that it did in v3.5e and I don't have the rules of v5 handy.

Comment: @DavidFoerster No, it is a separate question. By the way any damage bonus that gives *dice* is affected by criticals, while flat bonuses are not.

Answer (score 3):

> **Sneak Attack**
>
> [...] **Once per turn**, you can deal an extra 1d6 damage to one creature **you hit** with an attack **if you have advantage** on the attack roll. The attack must use a finesse or ranged weapon.
>
> You don't need advantage on the attack roll if another enemy of the target is within 5 feet of it, that enemy isn't incapacitated, and you don't have disadvantage on the attack roll.

&

> **Volley**
>
> You can use your action to make a ranged attack against any number of creatures within 10 feet of a point you can see within your weapon's range. You must have ammunition for each target, as normal, and you make a separate attack roll for each target.

---

You can only *Sneak Attack* **once per turn**. With you volley, you would either require advantage on the attack **OR** another enemy of the target standing 5ft next to it to apply *Sneak Attack*.

So, you can combine it, if the conditions of *Sneak Attack* are fulfilled, but only on **one target!**